# iOS simulator weird "broken glass" behavior, App only lists contacts groups

Tags: ios-simulator, contacts

I'm working on a two months old project that was working till today, without any changes except maybe XCode update from 4.4 to 4.5.

I use RHAddressBook to read contacts groups, which seems to be a very good framework, but got a weird behavior.

In this order :

- Simulating in iOS5 iPhone non retina : app displays a black screen, weird log :

`objc[31712]: Class _NSZombie_CFCalendar is implemented in both ?? and ??. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

- Simulating in iOS6 iPhone non retina : everything works fine, groups are loaded and displayed, no log
- Simulating in iOS5 iPhone non retina : app displays contact list but their seems to be a broken glass effect on the simulator display, and neither top or bottom bars are displayed, weird log again

Here is my storyboard (root view in navigation controller) :

[image]

And simulator screenshot for the same screen :

[image]

And the second screen (simple segue opening blank page) :

[image]

If some idea crosses your mind I'd be glad to hear it !

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: seems like this is an iPhone Simulator bug, I will try reinstalling it. On another app (SYGalleryExample from SYGallery) it displays it as if it was on an iPad, with the same broken glass effect, and here is another app perfectly working on production use :

EDIT 2: Reinstalling XCode, wiping out `~/Library/Developer` and `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator` folders didn't do anything. Seems like I'm going for a full system installation again.

[image]

EDIT 3: even iphone simulator "native" apps are active weird. Here is proof :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything fixed, Apple bug somewhere in my user files for iPhone Simulator on iOS5. To recap : the display of every app I built was screwed up, including app that were working yesterday without any change done till then.

Then I spotted also native apps were not OK, design was the iPad one on the simulated iPhone non retina device .

Logging in another session, launching the same native apps (settings, maps, etc) everything was fine.

Logged back on the original session, everything works again.

Hope this can help some future reader.

EDIT :

actually no, still not working. complete new install of osx on new hard drive, no time machine restore or whatsoever, run working project on ipad 5.0 simulator and still :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it only reproduced on iOS5, iOS6 worked fine.

This is how i managed to fix it:

The problem was that i had installed SwitchResX, which is a program that creates display profiles for mac. This application interfered with the resolution of the iPad simulator.

So my suggestion is to remove any applications that change your resolution or try a different display resolution.

Comment: Indeed, only on iOS5, is it still not working with the latest XCode ?